# extract url from javascript text using python

Tags: python, regex, linux, anaconda

i am using python and beautifulsoup to parse objects and i am trying to extract url using re.findall

```
<a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" href="javascript: void(0);"
onclick="if (confirm('Delete link
http://gorillavid.in/8538jm5bptgd')) { removeLink(71603335); }"><i
class="fa fa-trash "></i></a>
```

I am trying to extract url `https://gorillavid.in/97ylvj76qjeh`.

I am trying this expression:

```
re.search("Delete link\s* (.*?)',", data).group(1)
re.findall(r'(https?://[^\s]+)', link)
```

It's giving me error that its not a string.

Comment: it's hard to format your code, please reformat by yourself.

Comment: i am sorry its my first question in this site .i have reformatted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use findall to find the url you can use a capturing group:

[`'Delete link\s+(.+?)(?=')`](https://regex101.com/r/fozQxJ/1)

**Explanation**

- Match 'Delete link
- Match one or more whitespaces `\s+`
- Capture in a group any character one or more times no greedy (this contains the values you are looking for)
- A Positive lookahead`(?=`
- Which asserts that what follows is a `'`
- Close the Positive lookahead `)`

[Demo](http://rextester.com/NRUZ62265)

Comment: thanks it worked i forgot to put that answer as right answer .. thanks again